# Python requests.get() from inside a request will not complete

Tags: python, http, flask, python-requests, get

When I execute the line from inside a request:

```
page = requests.get("http://localhost:5000/some/page/")
```

with `DEBUG` logging turned on, the output is:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:5000
send: 'GET /some/page/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:5000\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0\r\n\r\n'
```

and execution will not progress past this point. Am I missing a step somewhere?

**Update:**

This is happening for requests that themselves contain a `requests.get()`. So, I think flask is trying to do two different things at once and the dev server is unable to handle that. That also explains why this seems to work on my staging server.

I've tried running Flask with `threaded=True`, but that didn't make a difference. Any ideas on a fix for the purposes of local dev and testing?

**Update2:**

Wrapping in `with app.test_client() as c:` and using `c.get()` works for localhost, but fails in staging

Comment: Is this all the code for the requester? Can you post the server side endpoint code as well?

Comment: To clarify, if you add `print(page.status_code)` after the requests.get() statement, nothing is printed?  What is listening to port 5000 on localhost - another python app?

Comment: Are you using localhost in staging as well? If that is so, it will certainly fail as localhost doesnt exist The other thing I think is you are trying to create a request at the source which is not very helpful. Try to use the functions if reusability is required.

Comment: @JasonM1 yes, it stops on the `requests.get()` line.
@abhishekkumar no, I adjust the url when not on localhost

Comment: Are you seeing any logging of connections or errors in server when client tries to connect? Have you tried curl or web-browser on that URL?